SUMIFS with multiple arrays or the "OR" listing
Would like to create a excel sumifs function, which taking arrays / listing as input for multiple criteria. Currently using 2019 version.
Did some research and thought of using sumifs(sum_range,criteria_range,{x;y},...) or sumifs(sum_range,criteria_range,{x,y},...).
Example, was essentially expecting all formulas to generate result of 4.


To understand the difference between {x;y} & {x,y} in sumifs formula

What cause the difference in results using different formula

Any excel formula out there that I could use for multiple criteria sumifs, and all requiring arrays/listing as input.
(For example, summing up column A,
with column B having XX or YY as input,
and column C having ZZ or WW as input,
and column D having UU or TT or UT as input
Was thinking something below, but it does not work:
sumifs(A1:A100,B1:B100,{"XX","YY"},C1:C100,{"ZZ","WW"},D1:D100,{"UU","TT","UT"})



From research I could do like sumifs(A1:A100,B1:B100,{"XX","YY"},C1:C100,TRANSPOSE({"ZZ","WW"})), but could not find any answer for 3 or more criteria.

You can't use more than 2 arrays. If you have a version that supports it, using FILTER is often the simplest solution.

All 6 formulas won't return the output of 4. Only the 2nd and 4th would return as it states when the criteria first is vertical it will sum with both the combinations of y and h, hence creating a combination of 4 that is {'f" "y"}, {"f" "h"}, {"g" "y"} and {"g" "h"} which means both the first vertical array can have either "y" and "h", as stated above by @Rory Sir, FILTER() would be best here!

Apologies, should have mentioned earlier that I was using 2019 version. Just did some checking and observed that FILTER is not available for my version.
Any other suggestion is highly appreciated!

I'd suggest a helper column using a formula like: =AND(OR(B1={"XX","YY"}),OR(C1={"ZZ","WW"}),OR(D1={"UU","TT","UT"})) then you can use that in SUMIF looking for TRUE.

You can't use more than two arrays with that syntax. Since you don't have FILTER, the simplest option to my mind is to use a helper column with a formula like:
=AND(OR(B1={"XX","YY"}),OR(C1={"ZZ","WW"}),OR(D1={"UU","TT","UT"}))

which will return TRUE/FALSE for each row. Then simply use this column as a single criterion column in a SUMIF formula.

Pardon me if I've misunderstood the need, but wouldn't this work
=SUMPRODUCT(C1:C5,((A1:A5="f") + (A1:A5="g")) * ((B1:B5="h")+(B1:B5="y")))

MMULT
with more flexible way of entering criteria as {…}
=SUMPRODUCT(
    C1:C5,
    (
        MMULT(--(A1:A5 = {"f", "g"}), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS({"f", "h"}), , 1, 0)) *
            MMULT(--(B1:B5 = {"h", "y"}), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS({"h", "y"}), , 1, 0))
    )
)

Update 2024-08-06

MMULT used in the manner here, is used for getting row totals by multiplying each value in each row with 1, obtained from SEQUENCE(… and then summing.
For adding single value criterion, simply add multiplication with the condition, for example * --(c1:c5 = "x")
For adding multiple values, add using MMULT
-- is used to convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0



Thanks for this! Just wondering if the above could cater for more than 2 lists/arrays?

Hoping that you would ask - will get to it in a bit, after morning coffee ;) Basically you would add multiplication for each additional condition (with MMULT).
